# Why my NAT is not working?

Tags: cisco, nat

This's my Topology! Routes and the communication between then its working

[image: Topology]

```
ISP 1

interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.248
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 clock rate 64000
!
```

---

```
ISP 2

interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.0.26 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 ip address 172.16.0.2 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
```

I configured a Point-to-Point Address 172.16.0.0/30, That's will be a NAT Address? Or I can use another Address?

Before, I used a `debug ip packet` and I saw the data flow normally, without change my source address. As I was bothere redid the entire project :/

That are the commands:

```
ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.0 172.16.0.1
ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.16 172.16.0.2
```

Well, I'm using the network address with a static configuration.. Mehh, that's wrong right? Should I use a dynamic NAT for that?

How would I know whether it's working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ip nat inside source static** *local-ip-address global-ip-address [group group-id]*

I shoud use local ip address and not network address! That was my error

```
ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.2 172.16.0.1
ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.18 172.16.0.2
```

Now, When the request out from PC 1 toward ISP 2 or beyond, the static configuration it's working!